# CorePlot: How do I create an x-Axis with dates as labels?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

CorePlot: How can I display dates as labels on the x-Axis, and how do i bind the scatter plot data points, so that they display on the right x?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CorePlot: x-Axis with dates, only the first date label is showing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029053/coreplot-x-axis-with-dates-only-the-first-date-label-is-showing)

Comment: If you need to change your question, edit it - don't post another question. Sorry I can't help you with your problem - I'm not very familiar with Core Plot.

Comment: sorry, for not knowing what to ask for exactly... I am somewhat at a loss about the concepts of core plot, that's why I don't know to what ask for exactly.

Comment: Have you looked at the example apps? The *Plot Gallery* has a demo of date labels on the x-axis.